# moving site from local to Ubuntu server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, pyrocms

I have been locally building a site using PyroCMS - works perfect but moving it to a new Ubuntu server I find problems.

This has been my process so far:

1. I move the files and database on to our Ubuntu server and set up, pointing to database.
2. I point to the home page and it works fine (apart from images showing), the database connection is right.
3. I then point to the admin URL "**sub.domain.com/admin**" and it says _"Not Found - The requested URL /events_training was not found on this server"_.
4. I get the same error when pointing to sub pages "**sub.domain.com/events_training**"
5. I made sure that mod-rewrite was enabled, but I still get the same error.
6. I try "sub.domain.com/index.php/admin" and get the same error.
7. I then set AllowOverride to "All" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default to make .htaccess files work and reload apache - this results in the home page showing nothing but a blank page, **sub.domain.com/admin** is also now blank.

I'm rather at a loss of what I should be checking next.

The following is what is in my .htaccess file...

```
# Multiple Environment config
# Set this to development, staging or production
SetEnv PYRO_ENV staging

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
# disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc with URL rewriting
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Automatically determine and set the PYRO_ENV variable
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.domain.com$
    #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:development]

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage.domain.com$
    #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:staging]

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
    #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]

# NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
#AllowOverride All
#RewriteBase /wherever/pyro/is

# Restrict your site to only one domain
# !important USE ONLY ONE OPTION

# Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$

# Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your Apache log files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

The environment setting in the .htaccess file was wrong - it should have been "production" matching the database config settings.